# Image reference decreases in quality after opening it in Blender

Tags: image

I decided to make a new car project from an image that would find myself. 
After a  few searches, I found a picture: https://drawingdatabase.com/audi-a6-2018/
The picture is a hi-res one, however, when I import it to blender via the *Properties* shelf in the *3D View*, the quality decreases to a point where it is nearly impossible to model. By default the site saves as GIF, i've tried saving it in other formats as well but to no avail. Help would be greatly aprreciated.

Comment: if I convert it in RVB and Jpeg it works

Comment: Thank you very much, i converted it online and it acutally worked!

Answer (score 1):

Convert the image to RVB and Jpeg
Answer submitted by moonboots
thank you